# Advent of Code 2018 day 1 part 2: find the first aggregated number that occures twice

Tags: programming-challenge, functional-programming, f#

I am using the coding puzzels of https://adventofcode.com for improving my F# skills.

**Problem:**

Day 1 Part 2:

Starting with frequency 0, a list of numbers should be added successive generating new frequencies. Searched is the first frequency which occurs twice. If the end of the list has been reached without success; the list should be processed again.

> **Example Input: [+1, -2, +3, +1]**
>
> - Current frequency  0, change of +1; resulting frequency  1.
> - Current frequency  1, change of -2; resulting frequency -1.
>     C* urrent frequency -1, change of +3; resulting frequency  2.
> - Current frequency  2, change of +1; resulting frequency  3.
>     (At this point, we continue from the start of the list.)
> - Current frequency  3, change of +1; resulting frequency  4.
> - Current frequency  4, change of -2; resulting frequency  2, which has already been seen.
>
> In this example, the first frequency reached twice is 2.

**Solution**

```
let input = [1;-2;3;1]

type State =
    | FinalState of int
    | IntermediateState of int * int Set

type State with
    static member Zero = IntermediateState(0, Set.empty.Add(0)) 

let foldIntermediateState (freqHistory: int Set, freq : int) : State =
    let isFinal = freqHistory |> Set.contains freq
    if isFinal then
        FinalState (freq)
    else
        IntermediateState (freq, freqHistory.Add(freq))

let foldState state value =
    match state with
        | FinalState _ -> state
        | IntermediateState (lastFreq, freqHistory) -> foldIntermediateState (freqHistory, lastFreq + value)

let rec processListRec state lst =
    let result = lst |> Seq.fold foldState state
    match result with
        | FinalState result -> printfn "The result is: %i" result
        | IntermediateState _ -> lst |> processListRec result

input |> Seq.map int |> processListRec State.Zero
```

**Questions**

In fact, I am proud to have found a solution without mutable states that looks (at least for me) functional! :D. So any feeback that helps improving the solution or even alternative function approches for solving that problem are welcome :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It also looks functional to me, and I like your use of union type `State`.

---

You can define the `Zero` static member of `State` as:

```
type State =
    | FinalState of int
    | IntermediateState of int * int Set
    static member Zero = IntermediateState(0, Set.empty.Add(0))
```

You don't have to create a separate `with`-definition.

---

In general I avoid writing the result to the console in the algorithm function it self. Instead it is more useful to return the result and let the caller handle that as needed:

```
let rec processListRec state lst =
    let result = lst |> Seq.fold foldState state
    match result with
    | FinalState result -> result
    | IntermediateState _ -> lst |> processListRec result
```

Used as:

```
printfn "%A" (processListRec State.Zero input)
```

---

You need some kind of stop condition or an input check if all changes are positive or negative.

For instance will `[1;1;1]` run forever, because no frequency will ever occur twice.

---

A raw recursive solution could be:

```
let findReoccurantFrequency input = 
    if (input |> List.groupBy (fun x -> x > 0)) |> List.length < 2 then 
        raise (Exception "Invalid input (only positive or negative changes)")
    else
        let rec runner lst freq freqs =
            if freqs |> List.contains freq then
                freq
            else
                let head, tail = if lst = [] then input.Head, input.Tail else lst.Head, lst.Tail
                runner tail (freq + head) (freq::freqs)
        runner input 0 []
```

I'm not saying that it's a better solution, just another approach for the exercise and inspiration. Especially I'm not proud of the input check.

---

**Edit**

As pointed out by JanDotNet in his comment, my input validation is poor, so it's maybe better to leave it out. Below is a revised version of my implementation using a `Set` instead of a `List` for the frequencies:

```
let findReoccurantFrequency input = 
    let rec runner lst freq freqs =
        match freqs |> Set.contains freq with
        | true -> freq
        | false ->
            let head, tail = if lst = [] then input |> List.head, input |> List.tail else lst.Head, lst.Tail
            runner tail (freq + head) (freqs.Add(freq))
    runner input 0 Set.empty
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The points are absolutly valid :). 2 small comments: a) Determining invalid input is not such easy (e.g. [3;-1] will also result in an endless loop) Therefore I would assume that the input is valid. b) I really like your recursive solution! It is much cleaner and less code :). Note that for the real problem statement (input of 1015 numbers which create a list of 145.146 freqs) it more appropriated to use a Set<int> instead of a list<int> for the freqs.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat : I don't know F#.

I liked your solution, the use of algebraic data types, pattern matching and use of list processing via fold and higher order functions are good.

However I'm trying to apply a functional style in python (which I'm learning) and I think there is a way to do this that use simple list data structures, with (list) comprehension or the equivalent

Here is my attempt in python to present an alternative approach

```
import functools
import itertools

fchanges = []
with open('frequency_input') as f:
    for line in f:
            fchanges.append(int(line))

frequencies = [sum(fchanges[:index]) for index in range(1, len(fchanges)+1)]
skew = frequencies[-1]

print('Skew is ' + str(skew))
accumulator = itertools.accumulate(itertools.cycle(fchanges))
prefix = itertools.takewhile(lambda x: (x + skew) not in frequencies, accumulator)

# takewhile consumes the value I'm looking for to check the predicate, hence this hack
# don't need the list, memory optimization - just need the length
plen = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x+1, prefix, 0)
accumulator = itertools.accumulate(itertools.cycle(fchanges))
print('found first repetition ' + str(next(itertools.islice(accumulator, plen, None)) + skew))
```

Happy to receive feedback on my attempt too for any observers.